# What is the meaning of ''or something and or something like that''?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of ''or something and or something like that'' in this sentence? So, I've seen something like this.

> Are you good **or something**?
>
> Do you have pencil **or something like that**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, it is a somewhat insulting sarcastic way of asking if they think they are "good".

In the second it is a request for a pencil or something that can perform the same work as a pencil. So, a pen would be acceptable as well.

Comment: Could you be more clear on the first example?

Comment: And can we say that they are same?

Comment: @Frank: 1. If I thought someone was being a Goody Two-shoes, I might say "are you good or something?" to imply they are overdoing their righteousness. 2. Grammatically they may be the same, but their meanings are very different.

Comment: Then could you be more clear? I want to learn what's different.

Comment: @Lernz: I'll explain more thoroughly, but I am not sure what I am unclear on. Can you go further?